# Creating object with calculated values

Tags: node.js

I would like to create an object that has both a stored value and a calculated value in node.

i.e.

```
function test(value) {
    this.value  = value;
    this.double = this.value * 2;
    this.even   = (this.value % 2 == 0)
}

var a = new test(1);
console.log(a);
```

Question: Is this the correct way to achieve this?

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: Added question, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this the correct way to achieve this?

Does the code produce the result you want? Then it's probably "correct" enough.

There are various ways to achieve what you want. Neither is more or less correct than the other.

Some questions you should be asking yourself:

- Do I want to compute the values upfront or on demand?
- If on demand: Do I want the values be accessible as simple properties or are method calls OK ?
- Do I want to provide more computed values in the future? How simple should it be to add a new one?
- How many of these objects will be created at runtime?

If you want to compute the values upfront, then the simplest solution would be to have a function that creates and returns a simple object:

```js
function makeObject(value) {
  return {
    value,
    double: value * 2,
    even: value % 2 == 0,
  };
}

const obj = makeObject(2);
console.log(obj);
console.log(obj.even);
```

If you want to compute the values on demand, you can achieve this with getters:

```js
function makeObject(value) {
  return {
    value,
    get double() {
     return this.value * 2;
    },
    get even() {
     return this.value % 2 == 0;
    },
  };
}

const obj = makeObject(2);
console.log(obj);
console.log(obj.even);
```

On the other hand, if you creating many of these objects, you might want to use a class and so that the value computation methods can be shared across instances:

```js
class Something {
  constructor(value) {
    this.value = value;
  }
 
  double() {
    return this.value * 2;
  }
  
  even() {
    return this.value % 2 == 0;
  }
}

const obj = new Something(2);
console.log(obj);
console.log(obj.even());
```

---

In the end, there isn't a right or wrong way. There are only ways that fulfill your requirements and those who don't. Of those who do, choose the one that is the "simplest" (for you to understand and to implement).

Comment: Excellent answer.